# Uhandled exception in converting string to double

Tags: c#, double

My code:

```
string sal = "2345.56";

Console.Writeline(Convert.ToDouble(sal) * .02);
```

Please help me with this exception:

> System.FormatException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Convert.ToDouble(string value)
```

This function encapsulates method

```
Number.ParseDouble(string value, NumberStyles option, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
```

The **numfmt** parameter depending of current culture.
So, looks like your current culture supports another double format, "2345,45" for example.
The better way is to use one of the overloaded **double.Parse()** method and specify culture explicitly.

One of the right example gives to you **Spencer K**

```
var sal = "23445.56";
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(sal, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)*.02);
```

Comment: please show me how by using the example because i fail to do it. i'm a novice in programming so please don't get upset with me i really need help

Comment: Look for post update. Watching to your comments, I suppose you should read something about c# before coding. The best for novice is [Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework](http://www.apress.com/9781430242338) by Andrew Troelsen

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = "2345.56";
double t;

bool result = double.TryParse(test, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out t);
MessageBox.Show(result ? "Worked! Value: " + t : "Didn't work.");
```

If TryParse is successful in converting, result will be true, and the double value will be stored in t.

Comment: When I use this example there is no output for this line

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with .NET Framework v4.5

```
string sal = "2345.56";
Console.Out.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(sal) * .02);
```

Result: 46.9112

Comment: I have installed .NET Framework v4.5.2 but still I don't see any change